# Table View in JavaFx how to define setCellValueFactory

Tags: java, javafx

Hello i trying create table view, with dynamically columns
I want to add in first column all headers except first one and another cells can be a 0 value

It's give me a error " java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2

I dont really understand how to definie setCellValueFactory

Ok

User adding Object in list, This list is set in columns header .

```
for(Object c : objectList){
    TableColumn<List<String>, String> table1 = new TableColumn<>();
    table1.setText(c.getName());
    table1.setCellValueFactory(data -> {
        List<String> rowValues = data.getValue();
        String cellValue= rowValues.get(objectList.indexOf(c));
        return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellValue);
    });
```

Now i trying add rows to table for example

I have table headers

```
|Row|Object1|Object2|
```

so i want to my table look like

```
|Row|Object1|Object2|

|Object1|0  |0      |

|Object2|0  |0      |




ObservableList<String> datal = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
    for(Object a: objectList){
        datal.clear();
            int index = objectList.indexOf(a);
        if(index > 0 ){
            datal.add(a.getName());
        }else{
            datal.add(objectList.get(index+ 1).getName());
        }

        for(int i = index+ 1; i <objectList.size() ;i++){
            datal.add("0");
        }
        tableview.getItems().add(datal);
```

But when i datal.clear() i get error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1, when i dont use this function all rows look this same

Edited

It's look ok but i need another set of zeroes in table

|Objects|Object1|Object2|Object3|

|Object1|null|0|0|

|Object2|null|null|0|

|Object3|null|null|null|

Comment: Can you give us a working example that we can run ourselves? I.e. the full code, the definition of table1, objectList, data1 ... It is also not really clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Where is the first code block in relation to the second? Is `c` in the same scope? How do you add values (lists) to the table?   

Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: first code block is in the same method with second cde block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the same list over and over again as item. Probably you intend to create new lists inside the loop:

```
for(Object a: objectList){
    ObservableList<String> datal = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    // datal.clear();
    ...
}
```

furthermore you assume there are at least `objectList.size()` items in every list, which won't be the case, unless all elements in `objectList` items are equal to the first one.

Therefore you need to therefore you need to check the size of the `item` list in the `cellValueFactory`:

```
table1.setCellValueFactory(data -> {
    List<String> rowValues = data.getValue();
    int index = objectList.indexOf(c);
    return index >= 0 && index < rowValues.size()
                 ? new SimpleStringProperty(rowValues.get(index)) // does just the same as ReadOnlyStringWrapper in this case
                 : null; // no value, if outside of valid index range
});
```

Otherwise you'll get those `IndexOutOfBoundsException`s for some of the rows...

Comment: Thank you but i have another question i can't set zeroes as in game table i introduce in previous post